# Method overriding and Functional Interface complie error

Tags: java-8, overriding, functional-interface

I have replicated an error that I ran into while using Java 8 `@FunctionalInterface` (eclipse). The following does not compile; `Refined` produces the error:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Functioner<TFunnel, TFan> {
    Function<TFunnel, TFan> funnelledThenFanned();
}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Receiver<T, TFan>
extends Functioner<Supplier<? extends T>, TFan> {}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Giver<TFunnel, T>
extends Functioner<TFunnel, Supplier<T>> {}

@FunctionalInterface
interface Refined<T, R>
extends Function<T, R>, Receiver<T, Supplier<R>>, Giver<Supplier<? extends T>, R> {

    @Override
    public abstract R apply(T arg);

    @Override
    public default Function<Supplier<? extends T>, Supplier<R>> funnelledThenFanned() {
        ...
    }

}
```

`Refined` extending all of `Function`, `Receiver` and `Giver` causes the error; remove any one of these, and the code compiles. Is this the correct behavior? If so, how can/should I refactor?

**UPDATE**

This seems to produce a similar error:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Another<TFunnel, T>
extends Functioner<TFunnel, Supplier<T>>, Giver<TFunnel, T> {

    public abstract void newMethod();

    @Override
    public default Function<TFunnel, Supplier<T>> funnelledThenFanned() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Also, I'll note that without `@FunctionalInterface` everything compiles; interface instances just cannot be expressed as a lambda.

Comment: What is the specific error you are seeing?

Comment: Provided code compiles without any error.

Comment: @marcus.ramsden **Invalid '@FunctionalInterface' annotation; Refined<T,R> is not a functional interface.** The compiler error states that `Refined` and `Another` interfaces are not functional interfaces. I'm not able to use lambdas and the '@FunctionalInterface' annotation produces its compile error.

Comment: I don't get any errors with latest JDK u112.

Comment: @Flown yes I have JDK u112. I am currently using Eclipse Mars; would that affect anything? I'm going to get Oxygen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [Eclipse bug 453552](https://bugs.eclipse.org/453552), which was fixed as of 4.6M1, so any Neon release (currently Neon.1, soon Neon.2) contains the fix.

Answer (score 1):

`Functioner` has an abstract method `funnelledThenFanned()`, and `Another` adds `newMethod()`, making *2* abstract methods, which exceeds the limit of *1*  imposed by [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).

There is no mystery here.

Comment: `Another` also defines `funnelledThenFanned()` which leaves `newMethod()` as the single abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from Eclipse Mars to Oxygen solved this problem.  Thank you.